# Getting "Cannot find table 0." Exception while uploading excel document using IExcelDataReader

Tags: c#

Exception "Cannot find table 0" is throwing while uploading excel sheet using IExcelDataReader.
Here is the sample code

```
    FileStream stream = File.Open(opFile.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    IExcelDataReader excelReader;
    if (FileExtension == "xlsx")
       excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
    else
       excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
    excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
    DataSet dsresult = excelReader.AsDataSet();
```

thank you

Comment: On which line is the error thrown?  Is this a valid xlsx?  Does it have a sheet1?

Comment: yes it is a valid xlsx and has a Sheet.Line  DataSet dsresult = excelReader.AsDataSet(); is throwing error